# Blazor itextsharp low resolution qr code in production

Tags: asp.net-core, itext, blazor, qr-code

I made a qr code pdf in blazor webassembly.
the problem is that in the debug environment (windows 10) everything looks fine but when I publish to windows server the QRCode looks low resolution.
I generate the pdf in server side then return byte array to client side and open to new tab.

```
 public byte[] ReportPDF(Item item)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var fontPath = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "Fonts", @"Varela Round.ttf");
        BaseFont varelaRound = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font detailsFnt = new Font(varelaRound, 2.5f, Font.NORMAL);
        Document pdf = new Document(new Rectangle(70f, 26f), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, memoryStream);

        pdf.Open();
        PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(3);
        header.LockedWidth = false;
        header.TotalWidth = 65;
        header.WidthPercentage = 95;
        header.DefaultCell.NoWrap = true;
        header.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine(item.PartName);
        sb.AppendLine($"מק\"ט {item.Makat}");
        sb.AppendLine($"מיקום {item.Location}");

        header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(sb.ToString(), detailsFnt)) { Colspan = 2, MinimumHeight = 20, Border = 0, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE });
        header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", detailsFnt)) { Colspan = 1, Border = 0 });

        BarcodeQRCode qrCode = new BarcodeQRCode(item.Makat,
            5, 5, null);
        iTextSharp.text.Image imgBarCode = qrCode.GetImage();
        imgBarCode.ScaleAbsolute(new Rectangle(24, 24));
        imgBarCode.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

        pdf.Add(header);
        pdf.Add(imgBarCode);

        pdf.Close();

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

[image: debug environment]

[image: production environment]